# Issue with Model Binding and Ajax form not catching model errors

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, model-binding

I have an issue that I am not sure how to solve.  I have a normal .net MVC 5 application that I have written a custom default model binder to work with unobtrusive validation and catch *HttpRequestValidationException* errors.

The model binder looks like this:

```
public class DefaultModelBinderWithHtmlValidation : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        try
        {
            return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        }
        catch (HttpRequestValidationException)
        {
            Trace.TraceWarning("Ilegal characters were found in field {0}", bindingContext.ModelMetadata.DisplayName ?? bindingContext.ModelName);
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, string.Format("Ilegal characters were found in field {0}.  No HTML is allowed.", bindingContext.ModelMetadata.DisplayName ?? bindingContext.ModelName));
        }

        //Cast the value provider to an IUnvalidatedValueProvider, which allows to skip validation
        IUnvalidatedValueProvider provider = bindingContext.ValueProvider as IUnvalidatedValueProvider;
        if (provider == null) return null;

        //Get the attempted value, skiping the validation
        var result = provider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName, skipValidation: true);
        Debug.Assert(result != null, "result is null");

        return result.AttemptedValue;
    }
}
```

and it works fabulous for normal binding and posts between views and controllers. However, I have noticed that when I use a form that contains *Ajax.BeginForm* things don't work as expected.

My controller is very simple:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HomeViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            return View(model);
        }
        else
        {
            return View(model);
        }

    }
```

In a normal non-ajax form post the model comes back with the errors and they are displayed as expected. In my ajax post the controller gets the model with errors and passes it back to the view but even though the model field has an error it isn't decorated or highlighted.

The field that I know is in error looks like this in the view:

```
          <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-xs-offset-1">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", aria_required = "true", @style = "text-transform:uppercase" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
```

The only difference between working correctly and not working correctly is changing the *Html.BeginForm* to a *Ajax.BeginForm*

My ajax options look like:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Home", null, new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    OnBegin = "onBegin",
    OnComplete = "onComplete",
    OnFailure = "showError"
}, new { id = "HomeForm" })) // set new Id name for  Form
```

My functions are really not doing much either:

```
 function onBegin() {
     $("#homeModal").toggle();
        }
function onComplete() {
    $("#homeModal").toggle();
      }
function showError(error) {
    alert('we have an error.');
    alert(error.responseText);
}
```

I have looked around and although I see other AJAX-related posts I can't seem to find one that deals with this in this way. If there are, please point me to them and I apologize for not catching them. I am sure I am missing something simple.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

-Dave

Comment: You have not specified an `UpdateTargetId` in your ajax options (or are you updating the DOM with the view you returned in the `OnComplete` function?

Comment: Well - I have tried it with and without a target. In this case i need it to totally replace the view.  I think that may be where the issue is, but I can't figure out the right way to do that.

Comment: Its a bit pointless to use ajax if you wanting to replace the view

Comment: hmm. Well I need for the view to refresh to display the model error(s) - don't know of another way to do that. This is a stub I am testing for other functionality and on the actual production form the MVC form will use ajax because it does partial view on some results.  But I still need to be able to validate the model fields and catch the error...

Comment: And I apologize if I am just not seeing the simpler solution.

Comment: Include a `<div id="formcontent">` inside your form, then include `UpdateTargetId = "formcontent"` and have the method return a partial view containing only the form controls so you update the DOM with the partial your returning

Comment: That's where I was headed.  Thanks!! I think that's the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stephen's solution works the best.

"
Include a `<div id="formcontent">` inside your form, then include `UpdateTargetId = "formcontent"` and have the method return a partial view containing only the form controls so you update the DOM with the partial your returning – Stephen Muecke 1 hour ago"

that's it!